# Dialog overlay with infinite expanding height in Facebook only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, jquery-ui-dialog

I think this is an `!important` issue. I have a dialog with a set overlay like this:

```
.ui-widget-overlay 
{
    width: 518px !important;
}
```

The height of the overlay will be set in my Javascript depending on what the page size is (It can be one of two sizes)

```
        if (!placeHolderVisibility) {
            //Code

            $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('overlayLarge');
        } else {
            //Code

            $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('overlaySmall');
        }
```

Here is the `overlaySmall` and `overlayLarge` css:

```
.overlaySmall
{
    height: 985px !important;
}

.overlayLarge
{
    height: 1167px !important;
}
```

I have other pages with dialog boxes and they do not have the issue.

```
.ui-widget-overlay 
{
    height: 413px !important;
    width: 510px !important;
}
```

When I try to inspect the overlay in firebug I notice that `!important` is not in the css, but I cannot get the initial height (it expands to fast)

**Edit** I think its a facebook issue with their auto resize

```
FB.init({ appId: appid, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(); //<-- Something wrong with this maybe??
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `!important`? It's generally a bad idea with better alternatives.

Comment: I need to use `!important` because if I don't then the size never gets overwritten.

Comment: ...only because `.ui-widget-overlay` uses `!important`, though.

Comment: That is true. Let me mess around with it a bit. I remember that there was a reason to use `!important` I just have to figure out what it was again

Comment: Yea if I get rid of the `!important` the css is overwritten by some other jquery css and the height will go to the max of the page

Comment: You just need to use a more-specific CSS selector than the jQuery one, or use the exact same selector but make sure that your CSS comes after jQuery's. Using `!important` breaks the natural cascading of CSS and makes maintenance much harder (as you're experiencing firsthand).

Comment: Yup I got rid of the `!important` lines and got a work around. That fixed it up. You can make that an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copypasta'd at request of the OP:

> Why are you using `!important`? It's generally a bad idea with better alternatives.
>
> You just need to use a more-specific CSS selector than the jQuery one, or use the exact same selector but make sure that your CSS comes after jQuery's. Using `!important` breaks the natural cascading of CSS and makes maintenance much harder (as you're experiencing firsthand).